# Difference between ApplicationContextInitializer and BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

What's the difference between ApplicationContextInitializer and BeanFactoryPostProcessor? When to implement what interface?

Comment: you can follow this bellow url: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455536/beanfactorypostprocessor-and-beanpostprocessor-in-lifecycle-events

Answer (score 5):

My understanding of their difference is mainly in the time when their callback method is called.

`ApplicationContextInitializer` allows you to do additional initialization before persistent bean definition is loaded (e.g. your `application-context.xml`). Useful when you want to select profiles before you will load definitions.

`BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is called when bean definitions are loaded but beans itself are not created. Great example is `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which replaces placeholders with concrete values.

You can dive deeper in relevant documentations.
[`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) and [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html)