# Inject repository in spring bean created programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to write custom JSF converter for entity classes.
I use spring-data and spring-boot in my project.

Know i have a lot of classes looks like `this:

```java
 @Component("myFirstConverter")
 class MyFirstConverter implements Converter {
    @Autowired
    private MyFirstRepository myFirstRepository;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
                              String value) {
    return myFirstRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(value));
    }
    //...

}
```

I created custom class EntityConverter. It works with CrudRepository. But i can't understand how to programmatically create array of beans and inject into each bean corresponded repository.

Know I tried to write **@Configuration** class with this code:

```java
 @Configuration
 class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  
       @Bean
       public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor registerConverters(ApplicationContext context) {
    Map<String, Class<? extends CrudRepository>> converterBeans = new HashMap<>();
    converterBeans.put("firstEntity", firstEntityRepository.class);
    converterBeans.put("secondEntity", secondEntity.class);
    return factory -> {
        for (val entry : converterBeans.entrySet()) {
            CrudRepository bean = context.getBean(entry.getValue()
            factory.registerSingleton(entry.getKey()
            .concat("Converter"), new EntityConverter(
                    entry.getKey(), bean));
        }
    };
```

But it doesn't work. Application failed in initialization.

```
 19:07:59.546 [WARN ] o.s.c.support.AbstractApplicationContext:551  - 
    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
    refresh attempt: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name 'myFirstRepository': Cannot create inner bean 
    '(inner bean)#1fdfafd2' of type 
    [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting 
    bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1fdfafd2': Cannot resolve 
    reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor 
    argument; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe46103]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe46103.<init>()Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fumoRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1fdfafd2' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1fdfafd2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe46103]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfigurati 
    on$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe46103.<init>()
```

**UPD:**

Answer WiPU allowed to solve the problem. I changed my registerConverters method like this:

```java
 @Configuration
 class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  
       @Bean
       public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor 
     registerConverters(ApplicationContext context) {
        Map<String, Class<? extends CrudRepository>> converterBeans = new HashMap<>();
    converterBeans.put("firstEntity", firstEntityRepository.class);
    converterBeans.put("secondEntity", secondEntity.class);
    return factory -> {
        BeanDefinitionRegistry beanFactory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) 
        factory;
        for (val entry : converterBeans.entrySet()) {
              BeanDefinitionBuilder b =

   BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(EntityConverter.class)
                            .addPropertyReference("repository", entry.getKey().concat("Repository"))
                    ;
            beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(entry.getKey().concat("Converter"), b.getBeanDefinition());
            factory.registerSingleton(entry.getKey()
            .concat("Converter"), new EntityConverter(
                    entry.getKey(), bean));
        }
    };
```

Comment: So you can get this to work if the claas where the injection neesa to take place is not a jsf converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is failing to instantiate your Repository Beans according to your shown Exception.

A `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is called after all bean definitions are loaded, but not yet instantiated. You can find details here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455536/beanfactorypostprocessor-and-beanpostprocessor-in-lifecycle-events)

You can try to register you beans later in the process when all other beans are already correctly instantiated. You can find some details here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051394/how-to-add-bean-instance-at-runtime-in-spring-webapplicationcontext)

At this point all your Repository should be already correctly instantiated and you can just add your additional `EntityConverter`

As alternative, if you need to inject your `EntityConverter` into other beans, you can register `BeanDefinitons`. Then Spring will instantiate your bean when the repositories are already created. [Link to JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/SingletonBeanRegistry.html#registerSingleton-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

regards,
WiPu

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's work. I used BeanDefinitionRegistry in my method registerConverters and addPropertyReference to concrete repository.